# Yes/No Button VBA Excel. The if-else function is not working

Tags: excel, vba

What I'm trying to achieve is that when you click **yes** the first user form should appear, if **no** the other user from should show:

```
Private Sub btnDataSecurity_Click()

Question = MsgBox("Is this client specific", vbYesNo)

If vbYes Then

With DBUnilever
    .StartUpPosition = 2
    .Top = (Application.Height / 2)
    .Left = (Application.Width / 2)
    .Show
End With
Unload Me

Else

With DataBreach
    .StartUpPosition = 2
    .Top = (Application.Height / 2)
    .Left = (Application.Width / 2)
    .Show
End With

End If

Unload Me

End Sub
```

The if-else function is not working for me. I don't know what went wrong. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: You need to check for the variable question, which is the one getting the answer to the msgbox

Answer (score 3):

Consider replacing:

```
If vbYes Then
```

with:

```
If Question = vbYes Then
```

*(there may be other errors in the posted code)*

Answer (score 1):

As Gary's Student said, you should replace: `If vbYes Then` with `If Question = vbYes Then`.
Since you posted the whole Sub and there's no `Dim` for `Question`, make sure that you're declaring it (as an `Integer`, 'cause that's the return type of `MsgBox`) before it's usage.